# Birt Report Indian Rupee formatting

Tags: java, format, report, birt, number-formatting

I want to format numbers based on Indian Rupee/Number format (basically commas) in Birt through scripting (for some conditional reasons).

if I use:

```
this.getStyle().numberFormat="#,##,##,##0.000";
```

It still adds commas after every 3 characters .. as in 12,345,678.000 but I want the number to be 1,23,45,678.000 in this format

Can you please advise

**EDIT**: Bug with BIRT raised as : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432211

Comment: It seems BIRT does not make use of the right "NumberFormat" class solving this natively. BIRT allows to format numbers using "java.text.NumberFormat", whereas the class handling indian format is "com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat". I think this is why it does not work. Though i was able to produce the expected format 1,23,45,678.000, but into a string format only, not a number. I can post the expression i used as answer, if a String datatype is ok for your context.

Comment: You may post so that it may help someone.. if not me :-).. Afterall, effort should not go wasted.. How do we raise this with Birt Admins/Community ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: set a custom format number

Here is a possible workaround, forcing BIRT to make use of com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat class. I don't know why indian format is not natively supported, you could report this in bugzilla of eclipse.org site.

- Edit your dataset
- Create a new computed column, select "String" datatype
- Enter as expression: (in the first line, replace "value" with the actual name of the numeric column containing values)

  ```
  var columnvalue=row["value"], customformat="#,##,##,##0.000"; //we can add here a test for conditional formatting
  if (columnvalue!=null){
    var symbols=Packages.com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols(new Packages.java.util.Locale("en","IN"));
    var formatter=Packages.com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat(customformat,symbols);
    var value=new Packages.java.math.BigDecimal(columnvalue.toString());
  formatter.format(value);
  }else{
    "-"
  }
  ```
- Click "Preview results" in the dataset editor, a new column should be added at the end with the expected format.

Comment: Thanks Dominique.. This is cool. I have raised the bug too as : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432211

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) by setting the locale to Indian setting.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
String str = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale).format(<your number>);
```

That's if you are looking for JAVA code to resolve your problem.

Comment: Is this for Birt Report scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

```
**you can use following javascript currency format and call it from BIRT.

function getSouthAsianCurrencyFormat(amount) 
{
var l,ftemp,temp,camount,k,adecimal;
var decimals=2;
var ptrn="##,##,###,##,##,###.##";
var ptrnLength=0;
var adecimal=0;
var counts = {};
var ch, index, len, count;
amount= Number(Math.round(amount+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
amount=amount.toFixed( decimals );
for (index = 0, len = ptrn.length; index < len; ++index) {
ch = ptrn.charAt(index); 
count = counts[ch];
counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
}
for (ch in counts) {
if(ch=="#"){
ptrnLength=counts[ch];
console.log(ch + " count: " + ptrnLength+"("+ptrn.length+")");
console.log( "amount length: " + amount.toString().length);
//console.log("decimalLength: "+decimalLength.toString().length);
}
}
if(counts['.']=0){
amount=amount+".00";
}

k=ptrn.toString().length;
l=amount.toString().length;
 ftemp=amount.toString();
 temp="";
 camount="";
 if(ptrnLength<(amount.toString().length-1)) return 0;
 else {
        k=k-1;
        l=l-1;
        for(i=l;i>-1;i--){
        if(ptrn.charAt(k)=="#" || ptrn.charAt(k)=="." ){
        camount=ftemp.charAt(i)+camount;            
        }
        else{
        camount=ptrn.charAt(k)+camount;
        k=k-1;
        if(ptrn.charAt(k)=="#"){
        camount=ftemp.charAt(i)+camount;
        }   
        }
        k=k-1;
     }   
     return (camount);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing the answer Imam - for answers like this - you should really add some explanation for the key elements that make this a solution/answer to the problem/question - this way the community will also understand what you did to address the question.